# Sample large xml/rss feed

Tags: jquery, xml, json, rss

Is there any place I could download large rss feed or xml feed, I want to test displaying the data in phases and check if the computer freezes up.
Also, there any examples out there i can use hat using xml , jquery and json to load result from xml or json in phases when user clicks "More" it get the next 10 or 500 records and populates a table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, ask one question at a time. Also, why can't you create the sample feed yourself? It should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a php script that works with that example:

```
search.php

<?php
header("Content-type", "application/json");
$term = $_GET['term'];
?>
[ 
 { "id": "Turdus pilaris", "label": "Fieldfare", "value": "Fieldfare" }, 
 { "id": "Falco eleonorae", "label": "Eleonora\'s Falcon", "value": "Eleonora\'s Falcon" },
 { "id": "Falco rusticolus", "label": "Gyr Falcon", "value": "Gyr Falcon" }, 
 { "id": "Falco biarmicus", "label": "Lanner Falcon", "value": "Lanner Falcon" }, 
 { "id": "Falco vespertinus", "label": "Red-footed Falcon", "value": "Red-footed Falcon" }, 
 { "id": "Falco cherrug", "label": "Saker Falcon", "value": "Saker Falcon" }, 
 { "id": "Falco peregrinus", "label": "Peregrine Falcon", "value": "Peregrine Falcon" }, 
 { "id": "Anas falcata", "label": "Falcated Duck", "value": "Falcated Duck" }, 
 { "id": "Emberiza spodocephala", "label": "Black-faced Bunting", "value": "Black-faced Bunting" }, 
 { "id": "Pelagodroma marina", "label": "White-Faced Storm-Petrel", "value": "White-Faced Storm-Petrel" } 
];
```

You can generate that json dynamically also. Just tell me if you need it.
Hope this helps. Cheers